# Defining inputs and fitness in ANN with GA Python

Tags: python, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I am attempting to create a program that can find the best solution for winning a game using NN and I was hoping to get some help from the wonderful community here.

The game is a strategy war game, you have your soldiers and a land you need to conquer. There is also the opponent's soldiers you need to be aware from them,
for every second you have a land in your possession you get a certain amount of points.

you have a lot of inputs that the engine writer created that you have access for example: where all the lands located on the map, where the other's opponent soldiers right now, if the land is already conquered or in the middle of conquering.

I've already integrated the ANN in the game engine and set the fitness to be the points he collected but the fitness stays on nothing+1,
i assume that the problem is that to capture a land you need to stay next to it for few seconds and i can't get him to learn how to do it the fitness stays on 1

I've tried a big population and a lot of generations but its not conquering and i dont know what to do.

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet I will just answer taking some assumptions.
(I'm also starting to experiment with NN and GA in Python too (MultiNEAT), so not an expert either ;) )

- The problem could be poor feedback to the genetic algorithm, so it can't select the best individuals. Try making your fitness score more fine grained, for example, making that every little movement towards an enemy soldier increases a little the fitness, instead of just scoring based on final points.
- What are your network outputs? Maybe the network's results are not being passed onto the game properly. I would make, for example, the output neurons targeting movement for soldiers and maybe some for reactions in case of proximity (I don't really know the game's mechanics). If you have a limited amount of possible answers from the network, it could be possible that those are just not enough to win the game, so no network can really score better.
- Are you waiting long enough? The bigger the problem, the more time it will take to find an answer, specially in slow computers. Try using the GPU to implement the Genetic algorithm to speed up the evaluations of networks, if speed proves to be an issue.

Good luck.